# how can I get catalyst help about root.pm?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am learning Catalyst from the book `the definitive guide to catalyst`. The catalyst's version is lower about 1.58, but now the stable catalyst and perl is different, So some file generated by helper is not exact as the book.

For example, the root.pm has `=head1 METHODS`.

- How Can I get the official help about the file framework? The code is beyond to Perl or Catalyst?
- What is the popular Perl/Catalyst BBS or website? This site may be not the popular site about Perl/Catalyst.

Answer (score 3):

`=head1 METHODS` is not code, but documentation (see the [POD format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html))

Your book should be fine. You can check out the documentation online:

- [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~zarquon/Catalyst-Manual-5.9004/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod)
- [Catalyst's website](http://www.catalystframework.org/) (you'll see a link to their latest book)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [mailing list which you can subscribe to](http://lists.scsys.co.uk/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/catalyst) and ask questions of, as well as search older discussion threads.

I suspect the problem you are having is pretty closely related to the issue you raised in your other question, and once you get your server starting you'll be OK.